# How do I run node command from the MacOS Shortcuts app "Run Shell Script" action?

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to run a node.js script from a "Shortcut". Unfortunately, when using the "Run Shell Script" action in a "Shortcut" in the MacOS Shortcuts App, it doesn't have access to all the CLI tools I have installed (such as node, nvm, npm, or even brew).

I eventually figured out that it has a different `$PATH` variable, and when I start the shell script by editing the PATH variable I can successfully run "node -v",

```
cd Documents/Projects/idimension/pm_scraper
node -v
```

[image: node -v]

but if I then try to actually run any node script, or try npm -v

```
cd Documents/Projects/idimension/pm_scraper
npm -v
```

then I get this same error referencing `cachedCwd = rawMethods.cwd();`:

```
cachedCwd = rawMethods.cwd();
^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, uv_cwd
at process.wrappedCwd [as cwd] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/does_own_process_state:126:28)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.nvm/versions/node/v18.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/depd/index.js:25:24)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1174:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kevinoconnor/.nvm/versions/node/v18.7.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/agentkeepalive/lib/agent.js:6:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1120:14) {
errno: -1,
code: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'uv_cwd'
}
```

[image: node index.js]

[image: npm -v]